# Recursion: Return number of items in list with an even number of characters

Tags: python, list, recursion, index-error

I am having trouble wrapping my head around the concept of recursion. Can someone help critique my code? I am trying to return the number of items in a list with an even number of digits recursively.

```
alist = ["hello", "is", "there", "anybody", "out", "there?"]


def evenItems(alist):
  
    if len(alist[0]) == 0:
        return 0
    if len(alist[0]) % 2 == 0:
        
        return evenItems(alist[1:len(alist)-1] + 1 ) 
        
    else:
        return evenItems(alist[1:len(alist)-1])
```

Comment: Does it not do that? What exactly is your question?

Comment: If you are looking for a review of working code, probably check whether this would be acceptable on our sibling site [codereview.se]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking for [codereview.se].

Comment: The best critic of your code right now is the python interpreter. It is giving you errors, which are pretty clear.

Answer (score 1):

#### Critique: in comments:

```
alist = ["hello", "is", "there", "anybody", "out", "there?"]


def evenItems(alist):
  
    if len(alist[0]) == 0: # The base case is when alist is empty. So use 'alist' instead of 'alist[0]' (alist[0] is the first element)
        return 0
    if len(alist[0]) % 2 == 0:
        # A few things here:
        # - the '+1' should be on the outside of the parenthesis because it should not be part of the recursive evenItems function call
        # - To get the rest of the list you could use alist[1:] (which is from index one to the end of the list)
        return evenItems(alist[1:len(alist)-1] + 1 ) 
       
    else:
        return evenItems(alist[1:len(alist)-1])
```

---

#### My Recommendation

I like to make different variables so that I can clearly see what I am dealing with. You see I use (currentWord and restOfList). For recursive function I also like to separate the program into Base Case and Recursive call (again, just for more clarity).

```
alist = ["hello", "is", "there", "anybody", "out", "there?"]


def evenItems(alist):

    # Base Case: If alist is empty  
    if len(alist) == 0:
        return 0
        
    # Recursive call
    currentWord = alist[0]
    restOfList = alist[1:]
            
    if len(currentWord) % 2 == 0:
        
        return evenItems(restOfList)  + 1
        
    else:
        return evenItems(restOfList)

print(evenItems(alist))
```

---

#### Debugging:

Recursion is difficult. I usually like to print out what happens at each call so I can understand it better.

```
alist = ["hello", "is", "there", "anybody", "out", "there?"]


def evenItems(alist, level):

    print("  " * level + "Enter evenItems. Level: " + str(level))
    # Base Case: If alist is empty  
    if len(alist) == 0:
        print("  " * level + "Exit evenItems list empty. Level: " + str(level))
        return 0
        
    # Recursive call
    currentWord = alist[0]
    print("  " * level + "Current Word is: " + currentWord)
    restOfList = alist[1:]
    print("  " * level + "Rest of List is: " + str(restOfList))

    currentEvenItemsCount = 0        
    if len(currentWord) % 2 == 0:
        
        currentEvenItemsCount = evenItems(restOfList, level + 1)  + 1
        
    else:
        currentEvenItemsCount = evenItems(restOfList, level + 1)

    print("  " * level + "Exit evenItems even word. Level: " + str(level))
    return currentEvenItemsCount

print(evenItems(alist, 0))
```

output

```
Enter evenItems. Level: 0
Current Word is: hello
Rest of List is: ['is', 'there', 'anybody', 'out', 'there?']
  Enter evenItems. Level: 1
  Current Word is: is
  Rest of List is: ['there', 'anybody', 'out', 'there?']
    Enter evenItems. Level: 2
    Current Word is: there
    Rest of List is: ['anybody', 'out', 'there?']
      Enter evenItems. Level: 3
      Current Word is: anybody
      Rest of List is: ['out', 'there?']
        Enter evenItems. Level: 4
        Current Word is: out
        Rest of List is: ['there?']
          Enter evenItems. Level: 5
          Current Word is: there?
          Rest of List is: []
            Enter evenItems. Level: 6
            Exit evenItems list empty. Level: 6
          Exit evenItems even word. Level: 5
        Exit evenItems even word. Level: 4
      Exit evenItems even word. Level: 3
    Exit evenItems even word. Level: 2
  Exit evenItems even word. Level: 1
Exit evenItems even word. Level: 0
2
```

Comment: +1 Another trick you can do to follow recursion is to use the debugger on your IDE e.g. Pycharm/VSCode etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider instead performing your check at the back of the list using **[negative indexing](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_string_negative_indexing.asp)** to get the last element and the sub list excluding the last element for the next recursive call:

```
def numEvenItems(alist):
    if len(alist) == 0:
        return 0
    return (1 if len(alist[-1]) % 2 == 0 else 0) + numEvenItems(alist[:-1])

lst = ["hello", "is", "there", "anybody", "out", "there?"]
print(numEvenItems(lst))
```

**Output:**

```
2
```

Try it **[here](https://repl.it/repls/MidnightblueWorthyPattern#main.py)**.